# HAML Check for Null

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Working on a learning management system. NOT a RoR person. Have the line of HAML to generate an average score based on quizzes taken:

```
="#{(QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => "user_id = #{@user.id}") * 100).round}%"
```

The quiz_results table has columns for used_id and score.

However, if there are no records in the quiz_results table, the page doesn't render. I want to check if any scores exist for that user id, and if so, to show the average. If none exist, I want to display "No quizzes taken." here's what I have:

```
19:             %td
20:                 -if QuizResult('score', :conditions => "user_id = #{@user.id}").exists?
21:                     ="#{(QuizResult.average('score', :conditions => "user_id = #{@user.id}") * 100).round}%"
22:                 -else
23:                     %em No quizzes taken
```

I get the following error:

"ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `QuizResult' for #ActionView::Base:0x7028c7f5cb88>) on line #20 of app/views/manage_users/show_all_users.haml:"

I've been struggling all day with this. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance, from an RoR noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that `QuizResult` is a model class. If that is the case then you cannot use it as a method to look up an instance.

There are various ways that you can look up an object by some condition, for example:

```
- if QuizResult.find_by_user_id(@user_id).present?
```

To check for null (or nil as its referred to in Ruby) you can use the `nil?` method that Ruby itself provides or the Rails convenience method `present?` which returns true unless the object is nil, an empty string or empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

You might check your quotes. For the `condiitions` hash, it looks like you should be using single quotes rather than doubles.